# Build iOS native code without -gmodules flag

Tags: ios, xcode, clang

I intentionally downgraded the clang version I'm compiling with in xcode to a special 3.6 version.

Now I've an error on a flag that was [added on a later version of clang](https://reviews.llvm.org/D11958)

```
clang-3.6: error: unknown argument: '-gmodules'
```

Which switch I should disable on Xcode to not add this flag on build ?